# Restarting BIND service getting error

Tags: ubuntu, dns, dhcp, dnsmasq, nslookup

When I restart the BIND service getting this error from syslog

```
  named[4960]: /etc/bind/named.conf:15: couldn't add command channel 127.0.0.1#953: address in use
```

Even when I execute nslookup 10.5.5.1

Ouput:

```
  Server:       10.5.5.1
  Address:  10.5.5.1#53

  ** server can't find 1.5.5.10.in-addr.arpa.: NXDOMAIN
```

Dhcp and dns running on same server. Dhcp subnet - 10.5.5.0/24. Ip address of the server is 10.5.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates that a process, almost certainly `named`, is still running and using port 953 on the loopback interface.

Try doing a `stop` and then a `start` instead of a restart.  If that doesn't work, then you'll need to force-kill the stuck `named` process and then do a `start`.

Comment: Now dhcp and dns hooks not working.. Only i am able to get the server ip address hostname only when I execute the nslookup 10.50.100.1 but other clients i am not able to get